# Nextjs Multiple dynamic Routes on the bases of ids

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, next.js

[image: 1]

Hi, I am working on the Nextjs project, and I have an issue, where I have Events->Event->Schedule.
I just want to click on the event it will be linked to the event, inside the event there will be a schedule that will be linked to the schedule component,
there will be multiple events, and the routing should be dynamic. Folder structure is visible in Pic

Comment: simple I want the result http://localhost:3000/events/1/schedule/1

Comment: In the folder events create a file [...schedule].jsx, this way you can have multiples params like http://localhost:3000/events/ok/schedule/test/etc. Then you have the next router to access the params

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Next.js documentation on Dynamic Routing:

https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

You would create a file structure similar to this:

```
pages/
-- events/
---- [eventId]/
------ schedule/
-------- [scheduleId].js
```

The last file would live at `pages/events/[eventId]/schedule/[scheduleId].js`. In that page file, you would have access to both `eventId` and `scheduleId` as route parameters to look up the appropriate event and schedule.

Comment: Thank you, Is the [eventId] a folder or file?
because there will be so many events inside the pages/events/

Comment: `[eventId]` is a folder that contains the `schedule` folder which contains the `[scheduleId].js` file